# ODATA V4 How to filter multiple not equal to 0's

Tags: odata, dynamics-365, odata-v4

I am trying to use ODATA with a filter that will only show data if a,b and c are all not equal to 0.

What I am trying to say is this:

```
#Data i want to get
a=1
b=0
c=0

#Also data i want to get
a=1
b=1
c=0

#Data i do not want to get
a=0
b=0
c=0
```

I tried doing `?$filter=a ne 0 and b ne 0 and c ne 0`, but that only gets me data where all values must be *not* 0. i.e. `a=1,b=1,c=1`

What i'm trying to say is: How can I filter to exclude data if only all values are 0?

I am trying to filter before processing in code because this will save me on average 9 seconds per-request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option can be using `not` operator.

You don't want to return data where all `a`, `b` and `c` are equal to `0`.

```
?$filter=not(a eq 0 and b eq 0 and c eq 0)
```

If `not` is not supported then alternative to `not(a eq 0 and b eq 0 and c eq 0)` is

```
?$filter=a ne 0 or b ne 0 or c ne 0
```

After clarification that the service is dynamics 365. It's [not possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/webservices/use-filter-expressions-in-odata-uris#:%7E:text=the%20United%20States.-,Alert,-%3A%20You%20can) to use OR operator in filter for two different properties

Comment: Sadly, this does not work, as i get this message: `"error": {
        "code": "BadRequest_MethodNotImplemented",
        "message": "Client requests that contain \"Not\" filter options are not supported by Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central OData web services.  CorrelationId:  bb19..."
    }`

Comment: @Tim-Bolhoeve Ok, I've added alternative without not operator

Comment: I tried the 'or' already, and sadly 'OR' is also not supported in ODATA:     `"error": {
        "code": "BadRequest_MethodNotImplemented",
        "message": "The 'OR' operator is not supported on distinct fields on an OData filter.  CorrelationId:  8d..."
    }`

Comment: @Tim-Bolhoeve Yes, I didn't know you are using dynamics 365. OR operator is [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/webservices/use-filter-expressions-in-odata-uris#:~:text=the%20United%20States.-,Alert,-%3A%20You%20can) for two different fields: